# Using QImage With QQuickImageProvider

Tags: c++, qml, qimage, qlist

I have created a class that inherits QQuickImageProvider Class,
but i want to use the `requestImage()` function of QQuickImageProvider to set the QImage variable , but i dont know how to do that as i need that QImage variable from a class object , which has been deifned in QML from ContextProperty and want to use the id variable as an index values to retrieve QImage from a List. Here is the main function code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    PageBuffer p;
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("p",&p);
   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
   engine.addImageProvider("images", imageProvider);

    return app.exec();
}
```

PageBuffer p contains a List of QImages that i need to present using QQuick ImageProvider when a certain index value for the List has been selected by the user.
Here is the snippet of QML code where i want to pass the index value to the imageprovider, it shows an Image Element that will display one of the elements from the List of the Qimages that is saved in the PageBuffer object:

```
    Image{
                    x: 4
                    y: 4
                    height : imagerec.height
                    visible: true
                    width : imagerec.width
                    anchors.fill: imagerec
                    source:fileUrl
                    Text{
                        id:txt
                        x: 0
                        y: 71
                        text:"Sketch"+(index+1)
                        horizontalAlignment: txt.AlignHCenter
                        font.family: "Tahoma"
                        color:"#ffffff"

                    }

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.rightMargin: -59
                        anchors.bottomMargin: -39
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: {
                            p.index=index;
                            p.image=mod.get(index).fileUrl
                           images.image=p.img
                          //  main.source="image://image/1"

                    //                                main.source=p.image

                                  //        console.log(mod.get(index).fileUrl)
                            //              main.source=p.image;

                            //   currentimage=m.image;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `objectName` of `p` in c++ code. 
Assume this name is `MyObject`. So now you can pass this name (as a string) to your image provider(`imageprovider` in this case):

```
main.source="image://imageprovider/MyObject"
```

As I understand you already have your own class, derived from `QQuickImageProvider` and overided `requestImage`. In your case `id` will be `"MyObject"`. So now you easy can get real class by its `objectName`:

```
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects()[0]);    
PageBuffer *p = window->findChild<PageBuffer *>(id);
```

I don't sure with accessing the root item, check it by yourself please.

**UPDATED:**

You can declare `ImageProvider` as:

imageprovider.h

```
class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    ImageProvider (QQmlEngine *engine,ImageType type, Flags flags = 0);
private:
    QQmlEngine *m_engine;
}
```

imageprovider.cpp

```
ImageProvider ::ImageProvider (QQmlEngine *engine, ImageType type, Flags flags)  :
    QQuickImageProvider(type,flags),
    m_engine(engine)
{
} 

QImage ImageProvider ::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(m_engine.rootObjects()[0]);    
    PageBuffer *p = window->findChild<PageBuffer *>(id);
    // do with p what you want
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider(&engine,QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,0); 
    PageBuffer p;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("p",&p);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.addImageProvider("images", imageProvider);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can u explain one more thing? the engine variable here was declared in main.cpp , how will i use it in the requestimage function?

Comment: you can pass a reference to QQuickEngine through ImageProvider constructor and store it in private member inside the class

Comment: I have declared object of ImageProvdier " ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider;" Can u explain how i should give reference to it?

Comment: i tried to use a function that gives reference to the  engine variable but when i copy it to another instance of QQuickengine it gives error

Comment: Thanks a lot!, but the pointer for pagebuffer is still returning null, what should i do?